# Reg Ex JS match content inside a style tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a RegEx that can match content inside a  tag.
Example:

```
<style>
.foo1{display:block;}
.foo2{display:none;}
</style>
```

The JS Reg Ex should return :

.foo1{display:block;}
.foo2{display:none;}

Please note that  can have attributes as in type="text/css"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
str.match( /<style[^>]*>([^<>]+)<\/style>/ )[1];
```